# Error Integrating Spring batch with spring-batch-admin-manager on Spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to integrate spring-batch-admin-manager with spring-boot-starter-batch together using spring-boot embedded tomcat configuration.

However I am have this error trace which I cant nail down:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.batch.configuration.BatchConfiguration.steps; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stepBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'stepBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6da887a9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.main.Application.main(Application.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.batch.configuration.BatchConfiguration.steps; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stepBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'stepBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6da887a9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stepBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'stepBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6da887a9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:530)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'stepBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6da887a9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6da887a9 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$607a70b7.jobRepository(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.stepBuilders(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:63)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$607a70b7.CGLIB$stepBuilders$7(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$607a70b7$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ac8c0a6a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$607a70b7.stepBuilders(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

This is my gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'notification-processor-service'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
jar {
    baseName = 'notification-processor-service'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

ext {
    springIntegrationVersion = '4.1.1.RELEASE'
    springIntegrationKafkaVersion = '1.0.0.M2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public'
    }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    compile('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.0.RELEASE') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }
    //SI
    // compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:$springIntegrationVersion")

    /* //kafka
     compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-kafka:$springIntegrationKafkaVersion") {
         exclude module: 'log4j'
         exclude module: 'jms'
         exclude module: 'jmxtools'
         exclude module: 'jmxri'
     }*/
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

I added those configurations as shown in this github example:

https://github.com/codecentric/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml")
public class ServletConfiguration {
}

 */
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml")
public class WebappConfiguration {

}
```

this is my batchConfiguration class:

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    WriteToKafkaTasklet writeToKafkaTasklet;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;


    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have sample code where you got this working of spring-batch-admin and spring-batch? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things here:

1. Don't use `@EnableBatchProcessing` with Spring Batch Admin.  SBA provides a number of the components out of the box.  If you're willing to use the latest and greatest, it provides everything `@EnableBatchProcessing` provides without using the annotation.
2. The stack trace you're getting is because `@EnableBatchProcessing` is registering a `StepScope` that uses dynamic subclassing, but Spring Batch Admin is also registering a `StepScope` that uses java proxies.  As mentioned, remove `@EnableBatchProcessing` and that should remove your stack trace.

That being said, if you're using currently released components, once you remove the `@EnableBatchProcessing`, you'll need to manually configure the two builders it provides.  Add the following XML to your override XML and you should be in business:

```
<bean id="jobBuilderFactory" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="jobRepository"/>
</bean>

<bean id="stepBuilderFactory" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

Keep your eye out for Spring Batch Admin 2.0.  That will have all of what is discussed here built in.  M1 should be coming out in the next couple weeks.

Comment: Would you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729750/best-approach-using-spring-batch-to-process-big-file/27736756#27736756 thank you.