# @StepScope within Spring batch throw exception when trying pass param

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am having hard time to combine Spring-batch with Spring-batch-admin using Spring-boot.

Because I am using Spring-batch-admin I had to disable @EnableBatchProcessing and I manually configured the two builders it provides.

that came from my question here:

[Error Integrating spring-batch and Spring-Batch-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724642/error-integrating-spring-batch-with-spring-batch-admin-manager-on-spring-boot)

Now I am trying to do simple scenario when I want to pass param from jobContext params into ItemReader using @StepScope and injection of the properties

I followed the example over here(the example is without spring-batch-admin and spring boot)

[using @StepScope explanation](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-2-jobparameters-executioncontext-and-stepscope/)

And I get this exception:

```
2015-01-06 18:22:09.852 ERROR 10260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Exception while closing step execution resources in step step2 in job MyTestJob

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e99a9c6b.close(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.close(TaskletStep.java:305)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:267)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:386)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.controller.BatchJobController.job1(BatchJobController.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:288)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.batch.admin.web.filter.ParameterUnpackerFilter.doFilterInternal(ParameterUnpackerFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-01-06 18:22:09.866  INFO 10260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=MyTestJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{pathToFile=snids.csv, date=1420561328719}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

This is how I create my Job via controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/job1")
    public @ResponseBody StatusResponse job1() {
        try {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("pathToFile", "snids.csv").addDate("date", new Date()).toJobParameters();
            jobLauncher.run(job1,jobParameters);
            return new StatusResponse(true);

        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException ex) {
            return new StatusResponse(false, "This job has been completed already!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Application.class:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.notification.processor.service"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:integration-context.xml","classpath:launch-context.xml"})
@PropertySource("file:///d://etc/mycompany/services/pushExecuterService/pushExecuterServices.properties")
//@Import({ ServletConfiguration.class, WebappConfiguration.class })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.printf("hello man");
    }
}
```

And BatchConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    private WriteToKafkaTasklet writeToKafkaTasklet;

    @Inject
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Autowired
    private DownloadFileTasklet downloadFileTasklet;

    @Inject
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Inject
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("MyTestJob").start(downloadFileFromETStep()).next(processFileStep()).next(pushToKafkaStep()).build();

    }


    private Step pushToKafkaStep() {
        return this.steps.get("step3").tasklet(writeToKafkaTasklet).build();
    }

    private Step downloadFileFromETStep() {
        return this.steps.get("step1").tasklet(downloadFileTasklet).build();
    }

    private static final String OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION = null;


    @Bean
    public Step processFileStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO>chunk(1) //important to be one in this case to commit after every line read
                .reader(reader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                       //  .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                        //    .listener(logProcessListener())
                        //     .faultTolerant()
                        //   .skipLimit(10) //default is set to 0
                        //     .skip(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter writer() {
        return new ItemWriter() {

            @Override
            public void write(List items) throws Exception {

                logger.debug("hello");
            }
        };
    }
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[pathToFile]}") String pathToFile){
        FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        itemReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(pathToFile));
        return itemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<PushItemDTO> lineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        //  lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);

        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[]{"SNID"});
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PushItemDTO> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PushItemDTO>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(PushItemDTO.class);


        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new PushItemFieldSetMapper());


        return lineMapper;
    }
}
```

Servlet Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml")
public class ServletConfiguration {
}
```

Webapp Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml")
public class WebappConfiguration {
}
```

Thank you

I edited my code and instead of @StepScope I added

```
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

as suggested.

Now I get different exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchJobController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.Job com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.controller.BatchJobController.job1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'job' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/notification/processor/service/batch/conf/flow/BatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'job' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processFileStep' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/notification/processor/service/batch/conf/flow/BatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'processFileStep' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.main.Application.main(Application.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.Job com.mycompany.notification.processor.service.controller.BatchJobController.job1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'job' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/notification/processor/service/batch/conf/flow/BatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory method 'job' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processFileStep' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/notification/processor/service/batch/conf/flow/BatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'processFileStep' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Batch Admin configures the StepScope via XML which provides for java proxying as the mechanism for proxies.  However, `@StepScope` uses dynamic subclasses.  In order for this to work, instead of using the `@StepScope` shortcut, use the following:

```
@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

In addition to the above update, you'll want to return the interface (instead of the implementation) so that it is proxied correctly.  So in this case, you'll want to return `ItemStreamReader` instead of `FlatFileItemReader`.

Comment: I did as you suggested and I got dif exception:  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory method 'processFileStep' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader
 at .....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader

Comment: Edited my  question so you can see it more clearly. thank you.

Comment: Can you update your configuration?  That stack trace doesn't make sense with the configuration as posted.

Comment: ok I updated the question. I have updated Application.class, BatchConfiguration.class, ServletConfiguration.class, WebappConfiguration.class . please check them out and let me know if anything else needed. thank you.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious in the configuration.  If you can throw the project (or a sample that re-creates the issue) onto github, I can take a deeper look.